# Jsoup get div contents

Tags: html, jsoup, src

- Hi,

I can't get the "src" content of this div class :

```
<div class="myclass"><img border=0 src="./images/myimage.jpg"></div>
```

I use

```
Els1 = doc1.getElementsByClass("myclass");
el=Els1.get(i)
```

but el.attr("src") or any other attributes returns emmpty

Conversely, 
el.html() is ok :

```
<img border="0" src="./images/myimage.jpg" />
```

Tried also

```
doc1 = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(el.outerHtml());
print (doc1.getElementsByAttribute("src").text());
```

with no success.

How can I get this src value ?

Thanks for any help,

Olivier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Jsoup Doc it should look somehow like this:

```
Element image = document.select("img").first();
String url = image.absUrl("src");
```

You also could use `String url = image.attr("abs:src");` instead of absUrl.

I can't test your case on my system right now, so i hope you ll handle it somehow with the Jsoup Docs (URL part)

[Jsoup Docs Working with URLs](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls)

Comment: Thanks. I get the relative url with attr("url") because absUrl and abs:url both return empty. May be because I have a parseBodyFragment before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should be doing, if you are using class attribute.

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("myclass");
String imageUrl = elements.attr("src");
```

And this one, if you are using id,

```
Element element = doc.getElementById("myid");
String imageUrl = element.attr("src");
```

This should just work fine.